# linq to sql - Inserting a class with null reference

Tags: linq-to-sql

I am using linq to sql for a quick project of mine (if I understood correctly, linq to sql is dead... right?).

Anyhows, problem occurs in the following situation:
I've got a class (table) that references other table. I don't load all tables that the first table is related to.

When I try inserting the object, which doesn't have some of its refernces populated (that hold a null value) I get a null exception. How do I insert that object without needing to connect each and every one of the table it's referenced to?

Comment: LINQ to SQL is **not** dead. They're still working on it and improving it.

Comment: so, what does this mean?
http://www.stephenforte.net/PermaLink,guid,bc1bc043-3cdc-4ac2-8b46-3c72ad1d61cf.aspx

Comment: @user - it more or less means that if Linq to SQL works well for you now then use it, don't get too wound up about what is or isn't coming in the future. It also means that separating your concerns i.e. confing Linq to SQL to a persistence layer (true more or less whatever your back end) is demonstrably as good an idea as it ever was.

Answer (score 0):

Check the IsForeignKey and CanBeNull attributes for the association properties, these can prevent null from being inserted.